# Adding materials/textures to an existing THREE.Mesh (three.js)

Tags: webgl, three.js, scenejs

I'm looking for the ability to pull images (from a database or wherever) and overlay these onto a THREE.Mesh (three.js) based on some user input. What I think I need to do is the following:

1) Create a new material with texture from an image and add to geometry

2) Determine the faces onto which the image will be overlaid

3) For each vertex, determine and assign the UV coordinates for the image

4) Change the materialIndex for each face to the new material

I'm just uncertain whether this will work and how to make the proper assignments to an existing Mesh. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Anyone know if this is possible/easier using another library such as SceneJS?

Comment: You will get more help if you show what you have tried -- preferably as a live example or jsfiddle.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle attempting to do what I outline above http://jsfiddle.net/YnuaZ/2/

Comment: I'm now wondering if I'd be able to create a single transparent texture for the entire mesh, then "draw" the images onto the texture where appropriate.

Comment: @Jeff R. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to create a new material, only a new texture and replace the material's one. Then you need to set the UVs of the vertices you need to. Then set `geometry.uvsNeedUpdate` to `true`.

Comment: The number of images and the number of faces each one would cover is unknown.  I start with one material for the entire model, then need to texture sections of the model as images are pulled from my server (per user request).  This is why I need to add materials on the fly (I think), unless I can set multiple textures for a material.

Comment: Is there a maximum number of images?

Comment: Ideally, there is no maximum, but let's say I go ahead and set one arbitrarily at 100 images.  Is it possible if I set a limit?

Comment: Ok but this still doesn't answer the question - if I have a mesh (constructor already called) - and I want to ADD a material to this mesh, how do I do this?